# Mover datos de una lista a otra

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero saber de algún ejemplo donde dos listas no ordenadas `<ul>` puedan trasportar sus datos de una a otra.

Por ejemplo: 
Supongamos que tenemos la `lista uno` y `lista dos`, cada una con datos diferentes. Quiero que todos los datos que están dentro de la `lista uno` se muevan para la `lista dos` al presionar un botón.

Comment: Reinos, te recomiendo que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edites tu pregunta con lo que has investigado e intentado hasta el momento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Estás buscando algo así?

```js
const lista1 = document.getElementById('lista-1');
const lista2 = document.getElementById('lista-2');

function moverItems() {
  Array.from(lista1.children).forEach((item) => mover(item));
}

function mover(item) {
  lista2.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<h2>Lista 1</h2>
<ol id="lista-1">
  <li>Nosotros</li>
  <li>ser</li>
  <li>items</li>
</ol>
<h2>Lista 2</h2>
<ol id="lista-2">
  <li>Nunca</li>
  <li>nos</li>
  <li>moveremos</li>
</ol>
<button onclick="moverItems()">Mover items</button>
```

---

Para cambiar en ambos sentidos, podrías hacerlo así (*El css no es necesario, solo para que sea un poquito más cómodo a la vista*):

```js
function moverItems(selectorOrigen, selectorDestino) {
  const origen = document.getElementById(selectorOrigen);
  const destino = document.getElementById(selectorDestino);

  Array.from(origen.children).forEach(
    (item) => mover(item, destino)
  );
}

function mover(item, destino) {
  destino.appendChild(item);
}
```

```css
.listas {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.listas > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='listas'>
  <div>
    <h2>Lista 1</h2>
    <ol id="lista-1">
      <li>Nosotros</li>
      <li>ser</li>
      <li>items</li>
    </ol>  
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Lista 2</h2>
    <ol id="lista-2">
      <li>Nunca</li>
      <li>nos</li>
      <li>moveremos</li>
    </ol> 
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Mover items</h2>
<button onclick="moverItems('lista-1', 'lista-2')">
  1 -a-&gt;2
</button>
<button onclick="moverItems('lista-2', 'lista-1')">
  1 &lt;-a- 2
</button>
```

Comment: Hola claro si , solo que Con el mismo código  ¿pasaría los datos de la lista dos a la lista uno?.

Comment: Con un solo botón quieres mover todos los ítems de la lista 1 hacia la lista 2. Y luego con el mismo botón mover todos los ítems de la lista 2 a la lista 1 dejando la lista 2 vacía? Perdón la pregunta, pero no me quedó muy claro la idea.

Comment: Con otro botón seria para mover todos los ítems de la lista 2 a la lista 1 dejando la lista 2 vacía

Comment: Ahí agregué ese caso también en mi respuesta :)

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias